# Python- How do you save changes on qTableView if its set to Editable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside, qtableview

I'm a newbie to Python language and I really need some help. I've set my tableview in editable and I would like to save the changes made. but how do I do that? Thank you.

Here's my code displaying database contents to qtableview:

```
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM [mspayroll].[dbo].[regular_employee]")
    head = cur.description
    num_fields = len(head)
    data = cur.fetchall()
    model = QStandardItemModel()

    field_names = [i[0] for i in head]

    model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(field_names)
    model.setColumnCount(num_fields)

    for column in data:
        row = []
        for attribute in column:
            item = QStandardItem(str(attribute))
            item.setEditable(True)
            row.append(item)
        model.appendRow(row)
    self.RegulartableView.setModel(model)
    con.commit()
```

Comment: Where do you want to save it?

Comment: @eyllanesc to the database where it is connected with. mssql

Comment: show your code please

Comment: done. i posted it

Comment: @cuburtrivera. This is what [QSqlTableModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsqltablemodel.html) is for.